# C# - better ways to validate if a string is a number other than int.TryParse()?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I find myself often needing to use `int.TryParse()` to test if a value is an integer. However, when using TryParse, I have to pass a reference variable to the function. So I find myself always needing to create a temp int to be passed in. Usually it looks something like:

`int my_temp_integer;`

`int.TryParse(potential_integer, my_temp_integer);`

I find this to be quite cumbersome considering that all I want is a simple true/false response, and I don't care about the actual parsed result. Is there a better way to approach this? Why isn't there an overloaded function where I can just pass the value I want to test and get a true/false response?

Thanks.

Comment: what should the value be for a fail?  I got used to TryParse.  It isn't a bad pattern, but I do know what you mean.  Have you tried wrapping it in an extension method?

Comment: I don't know why but in the time it took you to write this question you could have written the extension method.

Comment: Yes, I agree I could have written the helper function quicker than posting this question. But I'm curious if there is a better solution.

Comment: I saw a similar question for VB.Net. Their solution was to pass in Nothing as a keyword, e.g. Integer.TryParse("123", Nothing). I don't think we have this in C#.

Comment: Most answers here are not taking cultures into consideration, be aware of that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could write an extension method:

```
public static bool IsInt(this string pString)
{
   int value;
   return int.TryParse(pString, out value);
}
```

then your example becomes:

```
potential_integer.IsInt();
```

EDIT:
Lately I have been using a generic form of this.

```
public delegate bool TryParser<T>(string pString, out T pResult);

public static bool Is<T>(this string pString, TryParser<T> pTryParser)
{
   T val;
   return pTryParser(pString, out val);
}
```

Can then use it as follows; it's not perfect, but it's more concise than anything I've found:

```
"1234".Is<int>(int.TryParse);       // true
"asdf123".Is<int>(int.TryParse);    // false
"1.2345".Is<float>(float.TryParse); // true
"1000".Is<byte>(byte.TryParse);     // false
```

Theoretically, this would also work with custom `TryParse` methods, as long as you followed the same pattern as the official ones.

Update: If you maintain a static dictionary of `TryParse` methods by type, you can avoid having to ever directly pass the method. The dictionary can even be populated as needed with reflection.

Answer (score 8):

A simple solution is to create an extension method.

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static bool IsInt(this string s) {
        int i;  return Int.TryParse(s, out i);
    }
}
```

Then you just use it as so:

```
 string s = "123";

 if (s.IsInt())
     // do something.
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to actually convert the string, only test it, then you can use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)

something kinda like this (you may need to adjust this to fit your needs):

```
public bool IsInt(this string inputData)
{
    Regex isNumber = new Regex(@"^\d+$");
    Match m = isNumber.Match(inputData);

    return m.Success;
}
```

Comment: RegEx is waaaay slower than int.TryParse().  Granted, 99.9% of the time the difference will not matter, but 0.1% of the time it will to someone.

Comment: The problem with regex based solutions is that it's actually quite difficult to cover all cases. For example your case does not cover negative numbers and throusand separators.

Comment: It also won't take into account the limited range of `int`.

Comment: yes, I know... the OP said "other then using TryParse", this would be one possibility

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
bool isInt = str.TrimEnd( new char[]  {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'})
                .Length == 0;
```

Comment: What about thousands separators?

Comment: int.TryParse("1,234", out value) == false

Comment: I guess it could be added *if style includes the NumberStyles.AllowThousands flag* however since the OP did not mention this, nor does his example use the flag, the results are identical.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter alternative to  Muad'Dib above:

```
bool IsInt(string input)
{
    return new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^\d$").IsMatch(input);
}
```

/Hans